# .NET MAUI app: The type 'maui:MauiWinUIApplication' was not found. Unable to build the .NET MAUI app

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, .net-7.0, maui-windows

I have a problem with building a .NET MAUI app.
When I build the app I get this error message:

> *Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error XLS0414 The type 'maui:MauiWinUIApplication' was not found. Verify
> that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced
> assemblies have been built.*

[Screenshot: 'maui:MauiWinUIApplication' was not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi0cd.png)

And this one:

> *Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error CS1061 'App' does not contain a definition for 'InitializeComponent'
> and no accessible extension method 'InitializeComponent' accepting a
> first argument of type 'App' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?) Qit.QtimeUniversal.MAUI
> (net7.0-windows10.0.22621.0)**

The problem is in the App.xaml (and App.xaml.cs) file of the Windows platform which is in the Targets/.../Platforms/Windows folder:

[Screenshot: App.xaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tz9tc.png)

I also get this error:

> **Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error WMC9999 Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 2.*
>
> MSB4018   The "XamlCTask" task failed unexpectedly.
> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,
> position 2.

in this file:

.....nuget\packages\microsoft.windowsappsdk\1.2.221209.1\buildTransitive\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Markup.Compiler.interop.targets file:

I saw a similar issue described here:

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77335022/the-type-or-namespace-name-mauiwinuiapplication-does-not-exist-in-the-namespac](https://stackoverflow.com)

What I have tried so far:

- I have deleted all the bin and obj folder of all projects in the solution and then rebuild the solution. But this didn't solve it.
- I have checked if the .csproj file of the project the app.xaml.cs file is in is corrupted. But I could not find anything.
- The build action of the app.xaml file is set to MauiXaml. I have changed this to build action: page , but this was not right and didn't solve it. The build action is by default: MauiXaml if you create a new .NET MAUI app project in Visual Studio.

It might have something to do with a reference assembly which is not right.
But it used to work fine and now all for a sudden it failed to build.
Does anybody have an idea what might be the root cause of these issues?

Comment: You can try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it.  If it doesn’t work, try to restart the VS.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have already done these things but the problem is still there. I think I maybe need to reinstall the MAUI workloads although I'm not sure if this is causing this issue. Anymore suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

I think I found the answer here:
https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/5785

> I've seen this a couple of times and I think that is something that
> needs to be improved in Visual Studio. Notice in the top-right corner
> there is a dropdown that now says VisualLogger (net6.0-android) that
> means your editor now shows the code as it would be compiled on
> Android. Hence, it won't find the Windows specific stuff.
>
> Switch that dropdown to Windows and it should show fine.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcuoU.png)

This solved this issue:

> Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State Error
> XLS0414 The type 'maui:MauiWinUIApplication' was not found. Verify
> that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced
> assemblies have been built. Qit.QtimeUniversal.MAUI
> C:\Dev\QIT\QFS\QtimeMobileMAUI\Qit.QtimeUniversalSolution\Qit.QtimeUniversalSolution\Platforms\Windows\App.xaml
> 1

Now I can build the app again on Windows.
On android I still get a build error though.

Answer (score 0):

I renamed my Maui project from AppNameA to AppNameB. After some manual namespace renaming and using the "Sync Namespaces" function in VS, I found that the file below had the **WinUI part of its namespace renamed**, and that was causing the "the type 'maui:MauiWinUIApplication' was not found." error.

File:

```
Platforms\Windows\App.xaml.cs
```

Old Namespace:

```
namespace AppNameA.WinUI
```

New Namespace needs to be:

```
namespace AppNameB.WinUI
```